# Meteor Mysql and Session without MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mysql, session, meteor, session-variables

I am using Meteor with Mysqljs and have been able to achieve quite a number of things which i am gonna write a tutorial on.

The issue i am having is I want to be able to keep user session, if user logs in, I want to create a session that is not MongoDB dependent and use it both on client and server side.

Please any idea on how to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Meteor [Sessions](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) (`meteor add session`) to store key-value data (i.e. sessions) on the client side.

To use the value of a Session on the server side, simply retrieve its value using `Session.get("sessionName")` and pass that through a Meteor method.

Comment: The problem is Meteor's default is not persistent and i need a persistent session that wont be stored in localStorage

Comment: I'm not too sure how you would get persistent storage without MongoDB, though. Why do you need your sessions to not be MongoDB dependent?

Comment: The project is fully MySQL based and we have removed MongoDB from Meteor base.
The way we are current using it is by keeping the session data in localStorage and encrypting it to avoid readability but i'm not sure its fully the best way of doing things

Comment: What's stopping you from storing a Session in MySQL? It's persistent, and can be accessible from both client and server side. Encrypting client-accessible data does not seem like a good solution at all.